# the active directory is rebuilding indices

Tags: active-directory, raid

I have windows 2003 and active directory domain controller installed on it. 
I also have raid  0 + 1 on that server.

One disc failed. So that I removed it and everything was ok but I wanted to replace failed disc do that I bought one (unfortunately not the same but different - bigger space and company, there wasnt the same disc) and plugged it in.

Ihen system start there is message that this disc isnt a member of raid, then it boots normally till Windows.

In windows there is message:

The active directory is rebuilding indices.

Is there any possibility it can be solved ?

should I wait or sth ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the RAID utility (and this differs depending on make and model of your RAID controller) to add the new disk as a member and have it rebuild the array. This can normally be done either with a software tool inside Windows in this case, or during the BIOS POST settings phase of your RAID controller by pressing announced hotkeys.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange idea to boot Windows server with inconsistent array it installed on. Is your RAID array in fully operational state now? If it in "Degraded" state - any intensive file operations (incl. AD restoration) will perform slow. Use RAID utility to repair RAID.

Even if your RAID is ok - rebuilding AD indices is long process itself and unfortunately it's no warranty about success of this operation after a long time...

There is some suggestions in your case:

1)Wait some time... If it fails after a long time or 'hangs' - try to boot in "Safe mode" and check disk with chkdsk /f. Possibly your system partition has some file system errors after RAID fail.

2) Find your last backup and restore from it. For recovering AD database at minimum you should restore system state backup. To restore the System State data on a domain controller, you must first start your computer in Directory Services Restore Mode (ADRM).

Comment: Ok when it finished I couldnt even log in. Then I shutdowned server removed new disc and boot it. Now everything works fine. But only on 3 harddrives. I want to add new drive but I dont know how to do it cause when I inserted it there was a problem described above. What should I do to add new disc to RAID ? (repolace failed with new one)

Comment: If you can boot your server successfully now - perform a backup (just for any case). Then install new HDD and rebuild a RAID array (consult RAID manual for instructions - it may vary for different models)

Comment: A degraded RAID1 array does not perform slowly. It performs slowly when rebuilding.